# Chrome keeps locking me out of accounts

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am struggling to determine why Google Chrome started logging me out of my accounts after I close the browser.

- Chrome version: Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: Win 10 (64-bit)

I have read multiple threads regarding this issue but to no avail.

This is what I have tried already:

1. Chrome settings: I checked Cookie settings in Chrome (`Settings > Privacy > Content Settings > Cookies`).

   `Allow sites to save and read cookie data (recommended)` is enabled (on),
   the other two options are disabled (off).
2. Chrome reset: I reset Chrome to its default settings.
3. Chrome reinstall: I completely uninstalled Chrome. I ran CCleaner and Disk clean up and restarted my computer. I downloaded and installed Chrome from scratch.
4. Chrome vs Firefox: I logged into Gmail, LinkedIn and Stackoverflow in Chrome and in Firefox. I closed both browsers. I reopened both browsers. Firefox logs me in automatically into all accounts (as Chrome used to). Chrome doesn't log me into any of the accounts. I was prompted for login credentials.

I don't recall changing any settings in Chrome. I changed my password fairly recently but this issue started happening only a few days after I changed my password. So I assume the new password is not the root cause of this.

All the attempts described above failed to resolve the issue. And I am running out of ideas of what could be causing this and how to fix it.

Any tips and suggestions how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I tested all 4 suggestions made by Rakibul Islam.
The issue remains. I have another Win10 computer with identical version of Chrome.
The same issue is present on the other computer.

The latest scenario that somewhat works for me is as follows:

I logged into Chrome with my account and I added LastPass extension.
I logged into my LastPass (via the Chrome extension) and I get automatically re-logged in to Stackoverflow, Superuser and LinkedIn.
However, I keep being prompted for Gmail login despite checking "remember me on this device for 30 days".

I installed MalwareBytes, updated it with the latest definitiond and ran a system scan.
Nothing came back.

If there are any other scenarios to test, I will be happy to do so (with the exception of a full system reinstall :) ).

Thanks!

Comment: Fwiw, I have the exact same problem on a new PC installation with that very same Chrome version. Have never seen this problem before on previous installs.

Answer (score 2):

Still a number of things you may try. Hope these helps:

**1. Shuffle the Cookie Settings:**

- Go to `Settings` > `Advanced` > `Privacy and security` > `Content settings` > `Cookies`
- Enable `Keep local data only until you quit your browser`
- Close the Settings Tab
- Then close your browser
- Now, again repeat the above steps and disable `Keep local data only until you quit your browser`
- Close the Settings Tab
- Then close your browser

**2. Creating new user profile:**

- Go to `Settings` > `People` > `Manage other people` > `ADD PERSON`
- Then create new user and browse with that user to see the changes

**3. Deleting Cookie data from Chrome directory:**

- Quit your Browser
- Go to `"%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"` folder
- Delete the two files named `Cookies` and `Cookies-journal`
- Restart Chrome and try to login to different sites and enable `Remember Me` type things in those sites before hitting login button

**4. Using Anti-Malware:**

If all above fails, you are having a hard luck then. The problem you are facing is surely attached to your Google Chrome browser only, not your accounts status or password change issues. It might happen that any security software (Anti Virus, Windows Optimizer, etc.) you are using are set to automatically delete the cookies on browser shut down. Again, it may happen that some malware (Browser Hijacker or something like that) is creating problem. So, deep scan your PC with some good Anti-Malware software (Malwarebytes is recommended) to find out any malware causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After updating Chrome to the latest  version (Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit)) today, it appears that the issues has been resolved which seems to be the most straight forward solution.

Based on this, I assume that the issue was specifically related to the Chrome version Version 64.0.3282.119 (Official Build) (64-bit).

Comment: Exactly the same experience for me. Version 64.0.3282.140 (Official Build) (64-bit) works as expected.

Comment: Great. https://superuser.com/questions/1290950/google-chrome-doesnt-remember-my-google-account-sessions